# Rotas ou Urls em ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net

Eu tenho um aplicativo ASP.NET com WebForms ele esta hospedado da seguinte forma:
http://meusite.com.br/MeuAplicativo/Seguranca/Login.aspx.

Eu quero que quando digitar no navegador http://meusite.com.br/MeuAplicativo ele vá direto para http://meusite.com.br/MeuAplicativo/Seguranca/Login.aspx.

Eu sei que da para fazer isso no ASP.NET MVC através das rotas mas como posso fazer no WebForms?

Outro detalhe é que eu uso FormsAuthentication e as vezes quando digito: http://meusite.com.br/MeuAplicativo

Ele encaminha para: 
http://meusite.com.br/MeuAplicativo/Seguranca/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMeuAplicativo

Depois que eu faço login ele redireciona para http://meusite.com.br/MeuAplicativo e aparece erro de pagina não encontrada.

Comment: Tem isso no seu webConfig?  `<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Login.aspx" />`

Comment: @Marconi, você pode configurar uma Rota no WebForms, segue um link da MSDN: [ASP.NET Routing - Setting Default Values for URL Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#setting_default_values_for_url_parameters)

Comment: @TobyMosque mais isso que postei no comentario já deve resolver o problema dele. Eu usava também o `Set Start Page` clicando com botão direito em cima da página.

Comment: Marconi tem isso em meu Web.config: <forms name="login" loginUrl="~/Seguranca/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx"  timeout="120" />

Comment: @MauricioFerraz  já tentou `<forms name="login" loginUrl="~/Seguranca/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Seguranca/Login.aspx" timeout="120" />` ?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz muito provavel que vc já está tentando acessara página default por meio do `defaultUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx"`` e ele está retornando vc de volta pro login por não ter autenticado.

Comment: Adicionei isso em meu web config  
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Seguranca/Login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

Removi isso: 
<authorization>
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>

Aparentemente funcionou rodando localhost, vou subir para a hospedagem para testar.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Conseguiu?

Comment: @Marconi Fiquei alguns dias afastado, consegui sim obrigado.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz bom que pude ajudar.